# Android Studio error: This folder does not belong to a gradle project (Jsoup.jar)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, jsoup

Since last android studio (1.1.0) update I have one issue with Jsoup(1.8.1) Gradle and it compilation.

When I import jsoup.jar in the projects I receive a message that said

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

To fix this problem. I have tried:

1. -I try click on "Add now..." but dont fix the issue.
2. -Clean project.
3. -Rebuild project.
4. -Close and open Android Studio.

Nothing have worked.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

**Update 1:** I have updated to android-studio Beta(1.2) and now works fine. But i want use android-studio Stable version.

Comment: If the beta version works for you, why not continue using it ?

Comment: Because i want a stable version :D

Comment: You could try to export your project in Android Studio 1.2 and then import it into 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. On Mac OS X 10.10.3, upgading to version 1.2.2 of Android Studio solved this problem for me. I used option-return key press while hovering over the class name I wanted to reference and that caused Android Studio to add the appropriate import. Auto-completion seems to work as well in the IDE.